# Is this a metaphysical belief, and if so what's it called?

Tags: metaphysics, perception

Perceptual objects have no particular essence, except for having an indeterminate essence, so that some and only some properties can fulfil that role, and those properties are always general, instantiated in other perceptual objects.

Does that belief have a name and / or can it be clarified into falling under some more general position? If it makes no sense, please leave a comment and we'll try and work out what my description is missing. An example of what I mean may help.

A patch of red is essentially red, but there is no such thing as redness without properties like bloodiness, which is not essential to any red but some other red patches also have it.

Comment: What is "indeterminate essence" and "particular essence", do you mean something like [haecceity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haecceity)? If so, traditional Aristotelian essentialism had no haecceities anyway. And "there is no such thing as redness" probably means nominalism about universals. So this would be nominalist essentialism.

Comment: I don't know how to define "indeterminate essence" in received language, hence the question @Conifold

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to define, it seems to be just essence. Aristotle did not include anything "particular" into essences, only sharable properties.

Comment: it would be a type of essentialism for sure @Conifold i mean the bloodiness is not essential. so there is an essence but different properties can fulfil that role.

Comment: That's just generic essentialism. Any property can be essential to something and not to something else.

Comment: i don't think so @Conifold ... essentialism usually says that that the essence is invariant

Comment: It is, through time, this has nothing to do with which properties are in the essence. Or do you want "essential" properties that can be lost or acquired?

Comment: thanks @Conifold we'll see if anyone else gets it

Comment: Are you saying that all properties of perceptual objects are relational, like redness can only be defined in terms of its relation to other things like bloodiness, which itself can only be defined relationally?  Could one make an analogy to [mathematical structuralism](https://iep.utm.edu/m-struct/) or Quine's [global structuralism](https://www.jstor.org/stable/42968740)? (Quine also dismissed the idea of intrinsic properties, the SEP [properties](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/) article notes that he called them 'creatures of darkness')

Comment: For a 'structuralist' view of qualia see https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2014.00237/full

Comment: @Conifold according to Karl Popper here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essentialism), he uses essentialism whenever he means the opposite of nominalism. So at least in his perspective, it's impossible to be both a nominalist and hold essentialism for a sane intellect. Similar to Quine's view...

Comment: Perception gives a huge range of stimulus, not objects. Perceptions are later organized as sensations and sensations are later organized as conceptions: there exist only "conceptual objects", not "perceptual objects".

Answer (score 1):

You might argue that it is something like Śāntarakṣita's analysis of the two truths, with the ultimate truth as the conventional truth

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/saantarak-sita/

So he claims that there are no universals (the red has no bloodiness), and we refer to things by saying what they are not (not unbloody)' that is - I think - the ultimate truth. He also argues for [Yogacara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogachara) Buddhism, which claims that everything is perception only, and we cannot know what things really are; this is the conventional truth.

It seems that the absence of universals, only the referent of what would otherwise be universals, as the absence of an intentional object outside perception, does capture what I was trying to ask about. Dunno what that would be in analytic philosophy, or if any Buddhist has spun it that way

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the question is here. Essence is a term in ancient Greek philosophy that was later co-opted by both Islamic and Christian philosophy. It's not a belief as such.

Metaphysics was originally about the primary things that exist. It was named as such by a codifier of Aristotle's philosophy who named one of his books, which was un-named, as *Metaphysics*.

Since the primary things that exist, for monothiests, is God; and since for two millenia Western Eurasia was monotheistic is probably only natural that metaphysics became identified with theology or its like. Nevetheless, technically speaking, it is not. It's about the primary things that exist, whatever your beliefs and because of your beliefs.

The question about the essence of redness comes up as to whether redness is more essential, more primary, than the things that are red.

It was originally driven by Plato's theory of forms.

**edit**

You can say, pace Meinong's theory of objects, that Redness is an object with being but not existence.